# Filter the non-blank row in a DataFrame with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame `df2022`:

```
name    comment    product
Mike     good       2432
Tim                 1231   
Nite     bad        2234
Mike                3433 
Tim      bad        3432
```

I want to filter the rows with **the name that is not Mike and the comment that is not blank**. I did the following:

```
df2022new = df2022[(df2022['name'] != 'Mike') & df2022['comment'].isnull()]
```

However, it doesn't. It only works with the first part, so I think the second select non-blank part is wrong. What did I miss?

Comment: shouldn't it be `notna`: `df2022[(df2022['name'] != 'Mike') & df2022['comment'].notna()] `

Answer (score 0):

If you set `isnull()` to `== False` it will work:

```
df2022new = df2022[(df2022['name'] != 'Mike') & (df2022['comment'].isnull() == False)]
#   name comment  product
#2  Nite     bad     2234
#4   Tim     bad     3432
```

Comment: Rather use `~` or `notnull`...